# When should a join table be used vs id in the table in Ruby on Rails databases

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, join

So, a co-worker and I are having an argument on how to design a section of our database for a website we are working on. We both are fairly new to database design and can't say for sure which of our options are better so I was hopping to present the ideas and get the best advice on why one is better than the other or why they might be comprable to eachother.

To use as an example, assume we have three tables as follows in our database. Car_manufacturers, Car_models and Car_serialNumbers. Each Car_manufacturer has many Car_models, but each Car_model has only one Car_manufacturer. Also, each Car_model has many Car_serialNumbers, but each Car_serialNumber has only one Car_model. This relationship creates a downward tree where Car_manufactuere is the root followed by Car_model and Car_serialNumber.

The question is what is the best way to implement this in RUby on Rails using mysql. Below are the two ways we are arguing about.

My idea is that the primary key would be the id of the Car_manufacturer and it would be stored as a foreign key in the Car_model table. Then you create a has_many to a belongs_to relationship repectively between the Car_manufacturer and the Car_model. The same would be done from the Car_model to the Car_serialNumber. I believe this is best since seach child belongs to only one of its parents, the single foreign_key is simple and the relationship is easy to setup and manage in Ruby On Rails.

My co-workers idea is that we use join tables for everything. So, Car_manufactuere and Car_model would point to a completely separate table which would hold both keys. This table then acts as a proxy between the two. The same would be done for the Car_model and the Car_serialNumber.

So, as I see it, this creates extra data that isn't necessary. Why create a join table when the relationship can be done with less data by just storing the info in their own respective tables. Also, join tables for has_many and belongs_to relationships is not what they were intended for if I am understanding them right. Join tables are best for has_many to has_many realationships. Both ways can solve the same problem, but I believe my solution is simpler and simpler code creates less bugs which is my motivation for a solid design.

So, which is a better design for efficiency and simplicity? Which would provide the most benefit down the line? I have read a lot of material online, but none seem to answer this question. Any input into the question or links to helpful resources would be much appretiated.

Comment: Well, does this make sense: "car manufacturer has and belongs to many car models, car model has and belongs to many car serial numbers"? If so, your co-workers suggestion makes sense. If not, well, it doesn't. I believe your approach is correct.

Comment: To expand. This depends on the domain (cars). Can a car model be manufactured by different manufacturers? If so, then a many-to-many relationship would make sense.

Comment: As you explain it, you need only one-to-many relationship, which means you are corret. Co-workers solution is overkill for described situation.

Comment: So, given that my idea fits the relationship better, are there any benefits to the other way? Such as security gains or more flexibility in the long term. If the other way provides something more then my simpler way then it might be worth it, but I can't think of any benefits that my way doesn't already give. This is why I am in an argument with my co worker. He says there are benefits, but he can't explain to me any unique ones that my way doesn't also provide.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't bring myself to read all your text, so here's what I'd do:

---

[**Use an STI**](http://blog.thirst.co/post/14885390861/rails-single-table-inheritance)

```
#app/models/car.rb
Class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
   #fields - id, type, manufacturer_id, other, info, created_at, updated_at
   has_many :serials
   belongs_to :manufacturer
end

#app/models/cars/aventador.rb
Class Aventador < Car
   before_create :set_details

   def set_details
      self.manufacturer = Manufacturer.find_by name: "Lamborghini"
      self.site = "http://www.lamborghini.com/en/models/aventador-lp-700-4/overview/"
   end
end

#app/models/serial.rb
Class Serial < ActiveRecord::Base
   fields - id | car_id | serial | created_at | updated_at
   belongs_to :car
end

#app/models/manufacturer.rb
Class Manufacturer < ActiveRecord::Base
   fields - id | name | founded_at | created_at | updated_at
   has_many :cars
end
```

This will allow you to call:

```
aventadors = Aventador.all
aventadors.each do |lambo|
   #-> lambo.serials - shows all serials for the Aventadors in your fleet!
   #-> lambo.manufacturer.name - shows the manufacturer's name
end
```

The downside of this, although really cool, is you'll have to define a model for each car model, and define the manufacturer manually in each.

---

**Boring Way**

You could set it up the "boring" way as follows:

```
#app/models/car.rb
Class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
   #fields - id | manufacturer_id | other | items | created_at | updated_at
   has_many :serials
   belongs_to: manufacturer
end

#app/models/serial.rb
Class Serial < ActiveRecord::Base
   #fields - id | car_id | other | items | created_at | updated_at
   belongs_to :car
end

#app/models/manufacturers.rb
Class Manufacturer < ActiveRecord::Base
   #fields - id | other | items | created_at | updated_at
   has_many :cars
end
```

Comment: This looks similar to how I was going to set up my relationships and models as well. It's good to confirm what I was planning to implement. One thing though, is that I don't see having to manually define the manufacturer and other properties a downside. I see that as unavoidable and also makes the code a bit more readable with following the logic.

Comment: I guess that's right! Are you going to try the STI method? It would be REALLLLLLLY cool if you did :)

Comment: It's definitely going to be brought up. This question was mainly to just get some opinions and open up options if necessary. The example I gave above is nothing like the actual tables I will be using, but it appropriately shows some of the simpler relationships we will be dealing with.

Answer (score 1):

This is a difference between one-to-many ( your idea ) and many-to-many ( join tables ) relationships. Your data looks like hierarhical one-to-many, so implementation of your idea is simpler and more maintainable in this case.